# .strip("\n") not removing "\n" from string

Tags: python, string, strip

```
 def __init__(self, text):
     self.text = text.strip("\r").strip("\n").strip("\r").strip(" ")
     print("TEXT:"+text+";SELFTEXT:"+self.text)
```

`text` is inputed as "http://thehill.com/homenews/senate/376515-jeff-flake-there-will-be-a-republican-challenger-to-trump-in-2020\r\n"
and the `self.text` is still the same (does not remove the `\r` and the `\n`).

when this code is put on the Shell for Python it works as desired.
Any ideas?

edit: when the print statement is changed to 
        print("REPR:"+repr(text)+"\nTEXT:"+text+";SELFTEISXT:"+self.text)

the output for a similar string is:

REPR:'[http://thehill.com/homenews/senate/376548-lindsey-graham-war-with-north-korea-would-be-worth-it-in-the-long-run\r\n](http://thehill.com/homenews/senate/376548-lindsey-graham-war-with-north-korea-would-be-worth-it-in-the-long-run%5Cr%5Cn)'
TEXT:http://thehill.com/homenews/senate/376548-lindsey-graham-war-with-north-korea-would-be-worth-it-in-the-long-run\r\n;SELFTEISXT:http://thehill.com/homenews/senate/376548-lindsey-graham-war-with-north-korea-would-be-worth-it-in-the-long-run\r\n

Comment: Are you sure there aren't some other non-printable symbols after `text` that prevent `str.strip` from working? Can you print out `repr(text)` and see what the actual value is?

Comment: [mcve] please. (i.e., your code should be compilable without our having to guess and add your boilerplate code)

Comment: Since the `print` adds a newline, how do you know that the newline wasn't removed?  Did you try …`SELFTEXT:["+self.text+"]"` so that you have the `[]` pair around the text?  It's a good way of identifying problems.

Comment: If you are trying to get text from html, take a look at Beautiful Soup and similar libraries - htmlparser, html2text, newspaper3k. Maybe also newsml. For newspapers feeds beware of them cut and pasting from word docs.

Comment: @Ixx I am getting the text from html but the type of the variable is string.@Blender I added an edit of the output when I print repr(text) which seems to be the same.

Comment: @user202729 what extra code would you like?

Comment: @Blender THANK YOU SO MUCH! The repr(text) showed that it was actually "\n" in the file and not just a line break. So when I replaced the "\r" and the "\n" with "\\r" and "\\n" it worked!!

Comment: @DevBali Please read the [mcve] page. You need to provide some code that (1) is compilable, and (2) have the problem you're facing. Your code, if run as is, ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/XyElNU0hPj4zL7MkPl6jODUnTUehJLWiRNOKSwEEQCJ6IAEFW7C4XnFJUWaBhlJMkZImnJ2HxEYSV1DShBhSUJSZV6KhFOIaEWKlpA0yRlvJOtjVxw0qArdE8/9/AA)) doesn't have the problem you're describing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
text.replace("\r\n","")
```

Comment: Did not work, but that as well works in a shell. What could possibly be interfering with this?

Comment: The rest of your class

Answer (score 0):

Try using raw string. I have aadded `"r"` in `replace(r"\r\n", "")`

**EX:**

```
text =  """http://thehill.com/homenews/senate/376515-jeff-flake-there-will-be-a-republican-challenger-to-trump-in-2020\r\n"""
print(text)
print(text.replace(r"\r\n", "").strip())
```

**Output:**

```
http://thehill.com/homenews/senate/376515-jeff-flake-there-will-be-a-republican-challenger-to-trump-in-2020\r\n
http://thehill.com/homenews/senate/376515-jeff-flake-there-will-be-a-republican-challenger-to-trump-in-2020
```